# How can I avoid warnings when I apply function to a known list of arguments in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

How can I transform several values `a`,`b`,`c` etc. to `a'`,`b'`,`c'` etc, such that `x'=f(x)`?  The values are bound to specific names and their quantity is known at compile-time.

I tried to apply a function to a list in the following way:

```
let [a';b'] = List.map f [a;b] in ...
```

But it yields warning:

```
Warning P: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.                                                                                                         
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:                                                                                                          
[]
```

Any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a few functions for mapping on to uniform tuples, i.e.:

```
let map4 f (x,y,z,w) = (f x, f y, f z, f w)
let map3 f (x,y,z) = (f x, f y, f z)
let map2 f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

and then you can just use them whenever the need arises.

```
let (x',y') = map2 f (x,y)
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. You can silence the compiler by writing

```
match List.map f [a;b] with
  [a';b'] -> ...
| _ -> assert false
```

but that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is trying to help you here. It tells you that you are trying to assign an unknown list to `[a';b']` . What if one year later you change this code so that the first list, `[a;b]`, is refactored to a different place in the code so you don't see it, and the function `f` is changed so that it *sometimes* returns a different list? You will then *sometimes* get a run-time exception trying to match `[a';b']` with a wrong list. The compiler cannot check that the code is correct, hence the warning.

Why not write

```
 let (a', b', c') = ( f a, f b, f c);;
```

It's not so much more work to write this, but completely safe against any future changes in the code.

Comment: The change I should worry about here is if the `List.map` function changes, which is *very* unlikely.  The reason why I wouldn't like to write `(f a, f b, f c)` is that I have to write `f` three times, and if the function name is longer than `f`, it will look less nice than writing it once.